# how to open csv file (which is saved in windows) from unix command line

Tags: unix

I am new to UNIX.

could anyone please tell me how to open an EXCEL (.xls) file in windows from UNIX command line.

I have tried changing the extension of EXCEL file to (.csv) in windows , and opened it using:

```
command used : vi filename.csv
```

but , it opens as a new file . 
Is there an other command to get the spread sheet in EXCEL file. ??

Comment: Better asked on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) as it is not a specific programming question.

Comment: what do you expect to find in that file? My expectation would be to find a bunch of binary data. If you want .csv data, you have to use Excel File-SaveAs and then select the CSV from the drop-down list of 'SaveAs FileType' list. Then `vi filename.csv` will let you see the data. In unix environment, you're better off selecting the 'SaveAs FileType' of TAB DELIMITED. Unix tools don't natively deal with things like `"field1,more",123,text` very well (note the embedded comma). Good luck.